# Merge Sort returning wrong values

Tags: c++

I'm working on merge sort algorithm and i'm not getting the output I'm looking for. I'm inputing a file with 20 different numbers. The numbers in the file run through the program but it returns -842150451, -117594513 and -2147483648. mostly -842150451. I did try and change `merges(A, 0, n);` to  `merges(A, size of array A, n);` but that only gave the numbers and did not sort them. I also tried making p the largest value but had the same result as making p the array size. Any points on what I can change would be helpful.

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 using namespace std;

 void merge(int A[], int p, int q, int r) {

  int i;
  int j;
  int k;
  int n1 = q - p + 1;
  int n2 = r - q;

  double inf = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();


  int* L = new int[n1 + 1];
  int* R = new int[n2 + 1];


for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    L[i] = A[p + i - 1];
for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
    R[j] = A[q + j];

L[n1 + 1 ] = inf;
R[n2 + 1 ] = inf; 


i = 1;
j = 1;


for (k = p ; k < r; k++) {
    if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
        A[k] = L[i];
        i++;
    }
    else{
        A[k] = R[j];
        j++;
    }
}


}

void merges(int A[], int p, int r) {
if (p < r) {

    int q = floor((p + r) / 2);
    merges(A, p, q);
    merges(A, q + 1, r);

    merge(A, p, q, r);


}
}

void prin(int A[], int n) {

int j;
for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    printf("%d ", A[j]);
printf("\n");
}

int main()
{

fstream infile;
infile.open("number.txt");

if (infile.is_open()) {

    int i;
    int A[20];
    int n = sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A);
    int p = n;


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        infile >> A[i];
    }



    merges(A, 0, n);
    prin(A, n);


}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Right off the bat, `int* R = new int[n2 + 1]; R[n2 + 1 ] = inf;` is undefined behavior. You're trying to write out of bounds of the memory you've allocated. Furthermore, `floor` isn't needed in `floor((p + r) / 2);` as the result will already be an integer due to integer division.

Comment: You have 20 numbers in a file?  Can you post it so we can reproduce?

Comment: Your program clearly returns 0 always.

Comment: the number in the file are 6,4,64,9,87,45,1,5,48,63,7,12,90,586,84,8,22,56,999,76

Comment: You also don't need to allocate any memory for these arrays. Just `int L[n1], R[n2];` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::vector` instead of C style fixed arrays. You can use `std::vector<int>` and keep all the rest of your functions (APIs) the same. The pointer to the beginning of your array can be replaced with `a.data()` and the length of your array can be replaced with `a.size()`. The other things I would change is don't allocate memory for your `L` and `R` arrays, just declare them on the stack i.e. `int L[n1], R[n2];` Finally, get rid of the `inf` stuff, it makes no sense for what you're trying to do i.e. recursively divide your "array" into halves then merge it back together.

```
std::vector<int> a;
int number = 0;
std::ifstream infile("number.txt");
if (infile.is_open())
{
    while (infile >> number)
    {
        a.push_back(number);
    }
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Error opening file!" << std::endl;
}

// call your functions like this with the vector
prin(a.data(), a.size());
```